# how to map my godaddy domain into azure host service plan

Tags: azure, dns, mapping

I have an Azure website at site1.azurewebsites.net and a domain on GoDaddy for somesite.com

So I want to use my somesite.com domain to handle site1.azurewebsites.net I have followed Azure's instructions and set up

How would I change the URL it uses In Asp.net MVC Site ?

Comment: Could you please tell us what do you mean about "How would I change the URL it uses In Asp.net MVC Site ?". If you bind the custom domain with the azure web app, then you could access the azure web site by using the custom domain. Besides, we couldn't change the default xxx.azurewebsite.com url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a DNS issue and fix.

Your AzureWebsite  URL should be put down as the source for your CNAME record for your existing domain.

I.E     @   record points to   site1.azurewebsites.com

When a user goes to your URL, they are delivered the content from the Azure  URL, but still stay on the same URL.

Do not do the redirect answer with web.config, unless you want to change the URL of your site, to be the azure URL.   A redirect is not the correct fix.   Configuration of DNS records is

Answer (score -1):

You could set the URL rewrite in your web.config file to redirect your Azure Web Site to custom domain name.

Here is an example code that helps you redirect to your custom domain.

```
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yoursite.com/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

For more details, refer to this [blog post](http://zainrizvi.io/2016/04/07/block-default-azure-websites-domain/).

Comment: probably the worst way to go about it. this will result in url changing to azure's default domain, definitely not something to be done in any real life projects.